# React Native iOS TestFlight app is crashing on iOS 12.x.x versions only

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight, ios12

React Native iOS TestFlight app is crashing on my **iPad Mini 2, iOS 12.5.4**. It is working fine in all iOS 13, 14 and 15 versions

XCode console log obtained:-

Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x15685f7c0; com.mycompanyname.myappname; pid: -1> with error: Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID com.mycompanyname.myappname" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID com.mycompanyname.myappname, BKSProcessExitReason=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to start job, NSUnderlyingError=0x280c7c150 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process" UserInfo={BKLaunchdOperation=launch_get_running_pid_4SB, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to get pid for label UIKitApplication:com.mycompanyname.myappname[0x896][58], BKLaunchdJobLabel=UIKitApplication:com.mycompanyname.myappname[0x896][58], NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such process}}, BKSProcessJobLabel=UIKitApplication:com.mycompanyname.myappname[0x896][58], BSErrorCodeDescription=bootstrap-failed}

Used: **XCode 13.0, Node 14.x version, React-Native 0.64.2**, We are using Microsoft app center for building app. When we created Enterprise build with our enterprise account, it is working fine. **Only crashing on TestFlight build**

Is there any solution for this? Advance Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue?